# what is current_user when using session-less devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I have disabled sessions in my rails api with for example `config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth, :token_auth]`

Does it make sense to "logout" of the api? If it does how can I get current_user because the code below throws current_user =nil error or the warden.authenticate fails.

```
# class Api::V1::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  def create
   # create token
  end

  def destroy
    # We don't need this because the user is authenticated by the token.
    warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :store => false, :recall => "#{controller_path}#failure")
    current_user.reset_authentication_token!
    render :status => 200,
           :json => { :success => true,
                      :info => t("devise.sessions.signed_out"),
                      :data => {} }
  end
```

Comment: APIs are cookieless. You can't expect the client to keep or send back any cookies so there isn't a session to begin with. It does not make sense to log_out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An API has no state because it's not relying on the browser to cache anything.  Typically if you want to secure an API, you give each user some kind of access token (via the rendered html or in the javascript directly (see the `gon` gem)) and then operate the API over SSL, requiring each call to have that access token.

For example, you could call `https://mysite.com/api/v1/users?token=...`

And then get the `current_user` based on that token.

Alternatively, you can include the token in your header whenever you do an API call. Either way, you will want to secure it with SSL so that nobody routing the request (e.g. a fake Starbuck's wifi) can sniff the request, grab the token, and use it themselves.